# PostgreSQL: too many connections for role "rep" on slave server

Tags: postgresql

I tried to setup "master - 2 slaves" configuration by article on digitalocean (https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-master-slave-replication-on-postgresql-on-an-ubuntu-12-04-vps).

First slave successfully connected to master and works fine. Second slave cannot connect. From postgresql (second slave) log:

```
2015-11-02 11:17:35 MSK [14198-1] FATAL:  could not connect to the primary server: FATAL:  too many connections for role "rep"
```

From log of master server:

```
2015-11-02 11:17:32 MSK [18981-1] rep@[unknown] FATAL:  too many connections for role "rep"
```

Every slave need different user?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By default, postgresql limit connections for all roles. Resolution: set limit to -1 (ulimited) or something different:

```
ALTER ROLE rep CONNECTION LIMIT -1;
```

from [atlassian](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRAKB/'FATAL+too+many+connections'+error+when+using+PostgreSQL+database+due+to+user-specific+connection+limit)